# 404 error when passing "cat" parameter to URL

Tags: urls, 404-error, parameter

I encounter a strange problem with our WordPress site.

When I check the URL:

```
https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/
```

Everything is fine.

When I pass several parameters to the URL, for example:

```
https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/?os=Windows&param2=abc&param3=def

https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/?os=Windows
```

Both will be OK.

However, when I pass the parameter `cat=xxx` to the URL:

```
https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/?cat=Networking
```

I will get 404 not found error. It seems that only this parameter will cause problems. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Probably WordPress gets "cat" as a category query and tries to load it.
Tested in a project of mine and I also get a 404 error.

Comment: How to solve this problem?

Comment: Rename your paramether from "cat" to something else

Comment: The URL is found in 404 error log and initiated by GoogleBot, not mine. (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)